# Unable to sort on days of week

Tags: java, date

I am trying to sort some data on the basis of week days. The problem I am facing is,I am getting following output :-
THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY,SUNDAY,MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY

While i was expecting 
SUNDAY,MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY ...

Here is the code I am using

```
public class DateComperator implements Comparator<Map<String,String>> {

    public String sortingView;
    public String sortType;

    public DateComperator(String sortingView,String sortType){
        this.sortingView=sortingView;
        this.sortType=sortType;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(
        Map<String,String> o1, Map<String,String> o2) {
         Date date1 = null,date2 = null;

          String[] formats = {
              "MMM-yyyy",   "MMM-yyyy",

                "MM-dd-yyyy",     "MM-dd-yyyy",
                "MMM-d-yyyy",     "MMM-d-yyyy",
                "MM/dd/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy",
                "MMM/d/yyyy", "MMM/d/yyyy",
                "MMM-yy",   "MMM-yy",
                "MMMM",     "MMMM",
                "EEEE",     "EEEE",
                "yyyy",        "yyyy",
          };
         String format="";
for (String parse : formats) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(parse);
        try {
                    sdf.parse(o1.get(sortingView).replaceAll(" ",""));
                    format=parse;
//                    System.out.println("Printing the value of " + parse);
                    break;
                } catch (ParseException e) {

                }
            }
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            if(sortingView.equalsIgnoreCase("month")){
             date1 = sdf
                    .parse(o1.get(sortingView).replaceAll(" ",""));
            date2 = sdf
                    .parse(o2.get(sortingView).replaceAll(" ",""));
            }else{
            date1 = sdf
                    .parse(o1.get(sortingView).replaceAll(" ",""));
            date2 = sdf
                    .parse(o2.get(sortingView).replaceAll(" ",""));
        }

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DateComperator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        int i=date1.compareTo(date2);
        if(sortType.equalsIgnoreCase("desc")){
            return -i;
        }else{
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

This may be happening due to parsing of value to the date object using EEEE format. And it uses some default date like Mon Jan 05 00:00:00 IST 1970 for Monday and as so on. I am very new to this. 
Any help will be appreciated Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running the above?

Comment: This is part of my product code, It's not like i can give you a piece of code which directly runs. Sorry i cant do anything about it

Comment: Are you implementing your own date methods because you are told to/want to, or just not using Java date libraries because you don't know they are out there?

Comment: Why `DateComperator implements Comparator<Map<String,String>>` instead of `DateComparator implements Comparator<Date>`? I like *e* as much as the next *Elliott*, but one can be too familiar with ones vowels.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Because we are using our own custom comparator and using Collections.sort where we are passing two parameters,first one which is Map of String containing week days and second one is the object of date comparator.